# Is there anyway to upgrade PHP4 mysql client?

Tags: php, mysql, php4

I get the following error:

*Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client*

I know I can solve it with:

```
SET PASSWORD FOR user@localhost = OLD_PASSWORD('password');
```

But I want to know if there is another way to do it by using a different PHP mysql extension or something?

Comment: what os are you working on? how did you install php?

Comment: PHP4 is abandoned now. You should really upgrade to PHP5, which has newer libraries.

Comment: I run both PHP5 (module) and PHP4 (as cgi) on my dev system (windows, apache2), I am basically just curious if there is another way other than the above ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is to use `OLD_PASSWORD` as you've suggested, another option is to upgrade the MySQL client library and the PHP MySQL bindings. I don't know of any other option: there is no alternative library.

Comment: do you have any info on where to get an upgrade mysql client library / php bindings?